# sharepoint custom list

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have created a sharepoint custom list. List items contains various fields like name, email etc.

I want one field to be editable. Other fields should be read only.

Could anyone point in the right direction.

The other question is,

I am entering the data into sharepoint custom list thru the form created in sharepoint designer.

How can I make sure that same record will not be inserted by same logged in person.

Could anyone point me in right direction

Many thanks
Hari

Comment: thank you Marek. Next Time I will do it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Marek, I am developing this application on MOSS 2007. I cannot see list manager feature in my site feature. Could you kindly confirm wheather this feature will be available in MOSS 2007? Thanks a lot

Comment: The scope of this feature is **site collection**. You should go *Site Settings* of the top level site and then click *Site collection features*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

You can use [List Columns Manager](http://sptoolbasket.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SharePoint%20-%20List%20Columns%20Manager) from the [SharePoint Tool Basket](http://sptoolbasket.codeplex.com/) project to mark selected columns as read-only.

[image: SharePoint Tool Basket - List Columns Manager]

**Question 2**

You need to create [list item event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648923.aspx) and override the `ItemAdding` method to check for possible duplicates before an item is added to the list.